# Why can we pass optional arguments to new expressions but not to delete expressions?

Tags: c++, memory-management, delete-operator

A few questions have already been asked on this subject on stackoverflow, but I haven't seen any explaining the **rationale** behind the limitation of the delete expression.
To clarify the subject, I've tried to gather the facts as I've understood them in the three following remarks.

**Remark 1: *General new expression***
Let's consider any  "operator new" (no matter if it is the default global one, a version that overrides the default global one, an overloaded version or a class member version). Let's assume that we also have a matching "operator delete".
Assume that the prototypes are as follow:

```
void* operator new(size_t, T1, T2, ..., Tn); 
void operator delete(void*, T1, T2, ..., Tn);
```

We know that when the programmer types a new expression:

```
T* t = new(t1, ..., tn) T();
```

(where the types of t1, ..., tn are respectively T1, ... Tn)
the compiler automatically replaces this line with something like:

```
T* t;
void* raw = operator new(sizeof(T), t1, ..., tn); // or T::operator new(...)
try {
  t = new(raw) T(); 
}
catch (...) {
  operator delete(raw, t1, ..., tn); // or T::operator delete(...)
  throw;
}
```

**Remark 2: *delete expression - legal in some cases***
We know that when the programmer types this delete expression:

```
delete t;
```

(where the type of t is T)
the compiler automatically replaces this line with something like:

```
if (t) {
  t->~T();
  operator delete(t); // or T::operator delete(t);
}
```

We thus know that with the simple syntax "delete t;" we can implicitly and automatically call any "operator delete" that **takes the same arguments as the default global one** (it can be the default global one itself, a version that overrides the default global one, or a class member version that takes the same arguments as the default global one).

**Remark 3: *delete expression - illegal in general***
Let's consider any "operator delete" that **DOES NOT take the same arguments as the default global one** (it can be a global overloaded version or a class member version).
Assume that the prototype is as follow:

```
void operator delete(void*, T1, ..., Tn);
```

We would have liked to write a general delete expression:

```
delete(t1, ..., tn) t;
```

hoping that the compiler would automatically replace it with:

```
if (t) {
  t->~T();
  operator delete(t, t1, ..., tn); // or T::operator delete(...);
}
```

..., unfortunately we know that **"delete(t1, ..., tn) t;" is illegal**!

Thus, it is often recommended to write a template function like:

```
template<typename T> void destroy(T* t, T1 t1, ..., Tn tn) {
    if(t) {
        p->~T();
        operator delete(t, t1, ..., tn); // or T::operator delete(...); ?!
    }
}
```

which might be problematic (you must define one for each "operator delete", and you have to be careful because you cannot handle the same way global version and class member version).

**To sum up:**
We have a general new expression but no general delete expression.
Do you know the rationale behind what appears as such an inconsistency?

Comment: Can you elaborate on remark 1? I can't see (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/) any code like `void* operator new(size_t, T1, T2, ..., Tn);`

Comment: @RomanZaytsev  This prototype represents any possible "operator new". It could for example represent a user-defined overloaded version.

Answer (score 1):

Note that since C++11 and variadic template, you may write `destroy` once as:

```
// Helper to define has_operator_delete traits
template <typename T, typename ...Ts> std::false_type has_operator_delete_impl(...);
template <typename T, typename ...Ts> auto has_operator_delete_impl(int)
-> decltype(std::declval<T>().operator delete(nullptr, std::declval<Ts>()...),
            std::true_type{});

// traits to know if T has operator delete(void*, Ts...)
template <typename T, typename ...Ts>
using has_operator_delete = decltype(has_operator_delete_impl<T, Ts...>(0));
```

And then the `destroy` functions:

```
template<typename T, typename ...Ts>
std::enable_if_t<has_operator_delete<T, Ts...>::value>
destroy(T* t, Ts&&... ts)
{
    if (t) {
        t->~T();
        T::operator delete(t, std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
    }
}

template<typename T, typename ...Ts>
std::enable_if_t<!has_operator_delete<T, Ts...>::value>
destroy(T* t, Ts&&... ts)
{
    if (t) {
        t->~T();
        operator delete(t, std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a018bc70e0964241)

I don't know the rationale to not have a general delete expression. Perhaps it introduces ambiguity in parsing somewhere...